# Xcode color set missing light appearance

Tags: xcode, macos

Maybe a simple question, but I am trying to enable light/dark mode for my Mac app. I added a color set, but what appeared wasn't what I expected. Instead of three colors I just have two, Any and Dark appearance.

I tried looking around for a fix, but I wasn't able to find anyone talking about this. Does anyone know what's going on?

Here's a screenshot I took that shows what is happening.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Occam's razor. You don't need three! Any plus Dark means that if you give Dark a different value, Any applies only to Light.